# Why constructor property of object points to parent's constructor instead of F in extend function if constructor property is not overridden

Tags: javascript

I'm discerning the famous JS's `extend` function:

```
function extend(parent, child) {
    var F = new Function();
    F.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new F();
    //child.prototype.constructor = Child
}
```

I've commented out the line where the constructor property is overridden. If I create the objects in the following way:

```
var p = function p() {this.parent = true};
var c = function c() {this.child = true};
extend(p, c);
console.log((new c()).constructor); //outputs reference to `p` constructor, why?
```

My question is why the constructor references `var p = function p() {this.parent = true};` instead of anonymous function that variable `F` points to? The manual on constructor property states that `constructor property returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype` and the instance prototype `new F()` was created by anonymous function. So why does it point to the other thing?

**Update**

Is the following assumption I've made based on `HMR`'s answer correct?
When a new function is created, JS engine creates new empty object and sets `prototype` proprety of the function to point to this newly created object. Then JS engine adds a `constructor` property to this object pointing to the created function.

So now to my case. When `var F = new Function()` JS engine:
1) creates new `F` function
2) creates new object (let it be `oF`)
3) sets prototype `F.prototype = oF`
4) sets constructor `oF.constructor = F`

The same goes for `function p` which has its prototype `oP` with a constructor property set to `function p`. As we remember, `F.prototype` points to `oF` but after we execute the following line `F.prototype = parent.prototype` it is now points to `oP`. Then when we access `(new c()).constructor` property `new c()` object doesn't have it so JS engine starts looking backwards on prototypes and finds the property on `oP` pointing to `function p` - and this is excatly what I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a member can't be found on an instance then JS engine will look in the prototype chain. The prototype chain is a bunch of objects that have a `__proto__` of another object until it's null.

Please note that `__proto__` is a non standard property and used here to explain the object first used in the prototype chain.

Since you replaced child.prototype with an empty object that has `__proto__` of parent.prototype the JS engine cannot find constructor on c, `child.prototype` but then it'll find it on `child.prototype.__proto__` which is parent.prototype.

When you do:

```
child.prototype.constructor=child;
```

it adds it to child.prototype so it doesn't mutate parent.prototype which is in `child.prototype.__proto__`. This is called shadowing.

More on prototype and constructor functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).

**[update]**

The prototype chain after inherits looks like this:

```
insance of child (new c())
  => c.prototype === new F() so an empty object
    => p.prototype, set when you did F.prototype=parent.prototype
```

Comment: Thanks, please see an update to my question. Could you please check that my understanding is correct?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I didn't mention that since I understand that :). Best!

Comment: @Maximus Correct, you forgot to mention that setting child.prototype to an instance of F (new F()) basically sets the child prototype to an empty object (with no constructor property) with it's `__proto__` pointing to parent.prototype. That is why you can safely mutate child.prototype without affecting parent.prototype because parent.prototype is one level higher in the chain. Updated my answer to show the prototype chain and where it came from

Answer (score 0):

You should put

```
F.prototype = parent;
```

That way you did you're are saying "both constructor are the same", with the example I show, you will say "F constructor is equal parent constructor"

Comment: no, that's wrong. If parent has static properties then they'll end up in child.prototype plus it doesn't solve nor explain the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `child` constructor is effectively lost during that process.

```
function extend(parent, child) {
    // Create a completely blank anonymous function
    var F = new Function();

    // Give it all the same properties as the parent, including constructor
    F.prototype = parent.prototype;

    // Overwrite the childs prototype with an instance of the parent
    child.prototype = new F();
}
```

Since the `child` prototype is overwritten with an instance of `parent.prototype`, `child.prototype.constructor` is overwritten as well.

Personally, here's the extend function I use and it works beautifully.

```
function extend(Derived, Base) {
    Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
    Derived.constructor = Derived;
}
```

Comment: `Since the child prototype is overwritten with an instance of parent.prototype` if that were true then setting `child.prototype.constructor` would set `parent.prototype.constructor`  to be correct: child.prototype is set to an empty object who's `__proto__` is parent.prototype.

Comment: @HMR Sure, if you want to get pedantic about it. `__proto__` is still on the `child` prototype, even if it isn't the first link in the chain. This is still a valid explanation of the situation.

Comment: child prototype is overridden with an instance of F that has a prototype of parent.prototype. If child.prototype is set to be parent.prototype you could never mutate child.prototype without affecting parent.prototype and the statement `Since the child prototype is overwritten with an instance of parent.prototype` suggest child.prototype === parent.prototype parent.prototype cannot have instances either since it already is an instance.

Comment: @HMR Setting `child.prototype = parent.prototype` wouldn't prevent you from mutating child.prototype. It just means that mutating it would mutate the parent. You're right that the prototype is an empty object who's prototype points to parent.prototype. But I figure providing this level of detail to OP clouds the true cause behind why `child.constructor` does not point to `child`: because it has been overwritten on the prototype.